# File string matching using python

Tags: python, glob

I am looking for the best module/way in python, to pair files based on 2 segments of the filename string and perform a function on that pair and then move on to the find the next pair.   So in example below I want the files with A2000089 and 1.tif to pair together, then find the pair A2000097 and 1.tif and so on.  Can Glob do something like this?

```
MOD17A2H.A2000089.h10v04.006.2015137071411_tif__1.tif
MOD17A2H.A2000089.h10v04.006.2015137071411_tif__2.tif

MOD17A2H.A2000089.h10v04.006.2015137071400_tif__1.tif
MOD17A2H.A2000089.h10v04.006.2015137071400_tif__2.tif

MOD17A2H.A2000097.h10v04.006.2015137071311_tif__1.tif
MOD17A2H.A2000097.h10v04.006.2015137071311_tif__2.tif

MOD17A2H.A2000097.h10v04.006.2015137071300_tif__1.tif
MOD17A2H.A2000097.h10v04.006.2015137071300_tif__2.tif
```

Comment: There are a number of different ways you could solve this.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: `glob` cannot do this directly. What you could do is glob the files with `_1` and `_2` separately, and then pair them

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter says this isn't possible via glob directly.  A straightforward way to do this would be to pre-parse the pairs before you act on them.

```
import glob
import os
from collections import defaultdict


pairs = defaultdict(list)
for path in glob.glob('*.tif'):
    base, _ = os.path.basename(path).split('__')
    pairs[base].append(path)

assert all(len(pair) == 2 for pair in pairs.values())
```